# collection add event firing on view initialisation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have this code in my backbone application,

```
createNewProject: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.createNewProject = new app.CreateNewProject({ 
        collection: this.dropdownListProjectCollection
    });
}

app.CreateNewProject = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.modal',

    template: _.template( $("#tpl-create-new-project").html() ),

    events: {
        'click input[type="submit"]' : 'saveBasicProject'
    },

    initialize: function() {

        this.collection.on("add", console.log("added"));

        this.$el.find("h4").text("Create new project");

        this.$el.find(".modal-body").html( this.template() );

        this.render();

        return this;

    },
```

I am trying to detect when a model is added to the collection, and then eventually fire a method to render that new record. However I am having problem in that the `this.collection.on('add'...`) seems to run when ever the view is initialised and again when a model is saved, how can I only run the method when the model is saved, and not the view being initialised.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do `this.listenTo(this.collection, ...` in your view because when the view is removed it will remove the event and avoid memory leaks.

The add event will get fired on every `.set` on the collection. If you passed models on collection initialize this will happen `ctor -> reset -> add -> set` to add those models so you will get `reset` and `add` events.

What doesn't make any sense is that your collection should have initialize BEFORE you initialized the view so I don't know why you are getting that event unless you are subsequently adding more models.

To listen to a save event you can use these events on the collection:

`request` - when the request starts
`sync` - when the request has happened successfully
`error` - something went wrong

PS this is a shortcut for `this.$el.find` -> `this.$('.someselector')`